# API Gateway - How Deploy API works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

After **creating** API Gateway with two API names and integrating with lambda function,

AWS documentation recommends to **deploy** this API, as shown below:

### [image]

1) What does deploy API mean? How creating API gateway different from deploying API?

2) Does deploy API option internally create Cloud formation template? that creates a stack and deploy

Answer (score 2):

1.) Create API ([create-rest-api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/create-rest-api.html) from the cli) simply creates the API Gateway resource, but it does not create the method, stage, authorizer, etc. for your API Gateway.  Deploy API ([create-deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/create-deployment.html) from the cli) will deploy either to an already created stage, or create a new stage for deployment.

2.) No, it will not deploy a CloudFormation stack in your account.

Comment: How to troubleshoot such issue? https://stackoverflow.com/q/59108077/3317808